# How to start Mongo Db after download. Command ./mongod not working

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, nosql, mean-stack

> 2018-10-08T15:49:48.157+0530 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
>
> 2018-10-08T15:49:48.175+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=65956 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Mayurs-MacBook-Air.local
>
> 2018-10-08T15:49:48.175+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.2
>
> 2018-10-08T15:49:48.175+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: fc1573ba18aee42f97a3bb13b67af7d837826b47
>
> 2018-10-08T15:49:48.175+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
>
> 2018-10-08T15:49:48.175+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
>
> 2018-10-08T15:49:48.175+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
>
> 2018-10-08T15:49:48.175+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: 
>   x86_64
>
> 2018-10-08T15:49:48.175+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
>
> 2018-10-08T15:49:48.175+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
>
> 2018-10-08T15:49:48.175+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
>
> 2018-10-08T15:49:48.176+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
>
> 2018-10-08T15:49:48.176+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100

How can solve this?

Comment: Please make a folder named "data" and inside it make another folder named "db" in c drive. then run the command. as it is finding the "Data directory"

Answer (score 0):

In the default configuration, mongodb uses `/data/db` directory for storing its database files.

> 2018-10-08T15:49:48.175+0530 I STORAGE [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating

This shows that the directory does not exist, so you have to create it.

**Try:**

```
sudo mkdir /data
sudo mkdir /data/db
sudo mkdir /data/logs
```

I'm not sure if the last command will be needed, but just fire it to be safe.

An **alternative** to this would be to find the mongo config file (I don't know where it is on macOs) and then change the `/data/db` path inside it to your desired location that exists.

Comment: this is not a solution. I created directory. Not able to run mongo server using ./mongod.

Comment: You must be getting different error now. Post the logs again.

Comment: You might not have write permissions for the directory. Try running with `sudo`

Comment: Or ``sudo chown -R `id -un` /data/db`` and then run `./mongod`